# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0 while caling JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, nuget, visual-studio-2017

We are working in an asp.net web api project, using asp .net core and Visual Studio 2015. The project.json file looks like this (just listing entries which might be problematic):

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.3",
"Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.29",
"Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
},
"frameworks": {
"net461": {
  "frameworkAssemblies": {
    "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0"
  }
}
```

I am facing the issue while calling the SerializeObject method of JsonConvert class of NewtonSoft.Json assembly. The error is as shown below:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Checking the inner exception, I see the following:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}
```

I have started getting this issue only after I installed Visual Studio 2017 on my machine.

Shouldn't the correct dependency assembly which Newtonsoft.Json needs get resolved automatically ?

How should I go about troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: Does updating to the latest version of json.net fix the problem? It is currently at 10.0.3

Comment: `project.json` itself is the problem. Microsoft has dumped that experimental approach a long while ago. .NET Core SDK 1.x and 2.0 all use MSBuild based approach. Stop using VS2015 for .NET Core and don't bother yourself any more.

Comment: @KenTucker Are you talking about NewtonSoft.json ? Didn't try upgrading that, I will try.

Comment: @LexLi Yea we have that plan to get away with project.json, but not just yet.

Comment: Can`t reproduce. Could you reproduce this issue on the new asp.net web api project? If yes, could you please share more detail info so that we could reproduce this issue or share us the simple test sample?

Comment: @Randeep yes I was talking about NewtonSoft.json.net

Comment: @Randeep, how do you solve this problem&

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370524/how-to-fix-issue-with-newtonsoft-json-dependency