# How to fix issue with Newtonsoft.JSON dependency?

Tags: c#, .net

We have .NET Framework 4.6.2 on server. Our project uses the latest version of Newtonsoft.Json. When I try to run our project it fails with the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

I tried to extend web.config with runtime assemblyBinding - no results.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your application has been built against `Version=4.1.1.0` of the assembly. It is possible that on your local machine you have that version in the bin folder but on the server you do not have it. Make sure it exists on the server and make sure it is the correct version. If you are using a build server and it updates packages, check that out too.

Comment: @CodingYoshi the error is about `System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitive`, not JSON.NET itself

Comment: @f0rza that's a package dependency. The package was downloaded and installed when you added JSON.NET to your application and copied to the `bin/debug` and `bin/Release` folders when it was built. You probably forgot to copy it to the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please verify if the version of **System.Runtime.Serialization** currently is **4.1.1**.

Or try to install via nuget package console by using this command:

```
Install-Package System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives -Version 4.1.0
```

Comment: Thanks @PétersonCardoso. Installation of v.4.1.0 fixed this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to find what actually causes the issue: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MykolaTarasyuk.ReferenceConflictsAnalyser