# newtonsoft.json FileNotFoundException System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, runtime-error

I use .NETFramework(v4.5.2)  Newtonsoft.Json(11.0.0.0)
In most windows system, the software works well, but some run with error.

This Error happonend on `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Failed to load file or assembly "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Or one of its dependencies.

Comment: see [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370524/how-to-fix-issue-with-newtonsoft-json-dependency)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix issue with Newtonsoft.JSON dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370524/how-to-fix-issue-with-newtonsoft-json-dependency)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using NuGet. I delete the Newtonsoft.Json (download by hand) in reference, and download the same version again by NuGet.